# Derive linear function from normal angle vector and location vector

Tags: functions, vectors

I have a normal vector (x, y) representing the angle of the line and another one representing a point crossed by the line, aka location.

How can I turn this into a $y = mx + b$ function?

I started with $(x + location.x) * angle.x + (y + location.y) * angle.y = 0$ but I don't think that's right and I'm just confused now.

Comment: You’re close. What do you get if you plug the coordinates of the known point into this equation? What should you get?

Comment: That’s not what I’m asking you. I’m asking you what you get if you substitute `location.x` and `location.y` for `x` and `y` in your equation.

Comment: Incidentally, MathJax is used here for formatting mathematical expressions. You can find a quick reference and tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Note, too, that if the line is vertical, it can’t be described by an equation of the form $y=mx+b$.

Comment: Thanks @amd,
I ended up finding the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571294/line-equation-with-angle. Can't mark as duplication since it isn't math.stackexchange?